# How to Rewrite FSM not to use Latches

Tags: vhdl

I have an FSM and it works. The synthesizer, however, complains that there are latches for "acc_x", "acc_y", and "data_out" and I understand why and why it is bad. I have no idea, however, how to rewrite the FSM so the state-part goes to the clocked process. Any ideas where to start from? Here is the code of the FSM:

---

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity storage is
    port
    (
        clk_in                           : in  std_logic;
        reset                            : in  std_logic;
        element_in                       : in  std_logic;
        data_in                          : in  signed(11 downto 0);
        addr                             : in  unsigned(9 downto 0);
        add                              : in  std_logic; -- add = '1' means add to RAM
                                                          -- add = '0' means write to RAM
        dump                             : in  std_logic;
        element_out                      : out std_logic;
        data_out                         : out signed(31 downto 0)
    );
end storage;

architecture rtl of storage is
    component bram is
    port
    (
        clk                              : in  std_logic;
        we                               : in  std_logic;
        en                               : in  std_logic;
        addr                             : in  unsigned(9 downto 0);
        di                               : in  signed(31 downto 0);
        do                               : out signed(31 downto 0)
    );
    end component bram;

    type state is (st_startwait, st_add, st_write);

    signal current_state                 : state := st_startwait;
    signal next_state                    : state := st_startwait;

    signal we                            : std_logic;
    signal en                            : std_logic;
    signal di                            : signed(31 downto 0);
    signal do                            : signed(31 downto 0);

    signal acc_x                         : signed(31 downto 0);
    signal acc_y                         : signed(31 downto 0);
begin
    ram : bram port map
    (
        clk  => clk_in,
        we   => we,
        en   => en,
        addr => addr,
        di   => di,
        do   => do  
    );

    process(clk_in)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_in) then
            if (reset = '1') then
                current_state           <= st_startwait;
            else
                current_state           <= next_state;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(current_state, element_in, add, dump, data_in, do, acc_x, acc_y)
    begin
        element_out                     <= '0';

        en                              <= '1';
        we                              <= '0';

        di                              <= (others => '0');

        case current_state is
            when st_startwait =>          
                if (element_in = '1') then
                    acc_x               <= resize(data_in, acc_x'length);

                    next_state          <= st_add;
                else
                    next_state          <= st_startwait;
                end if;
            when st_add =>
                if (add = '1') then
                    acc_y               <= acc_x + do;
                else
                    acc_y               <= acc_x;
                end if;

                next_state              <= st_write;
            when st_write =>      
                if (dump = '1') then
                    data_out            <= acc_y;
                    element_out         <= '1';
                else
                    di                  <= acc_y;
                    we                  <= '1';
                end if;

                next_state              <= st_startwait;
        end case;
    end process;  
end rtl;
```

---

Comment: Search for "single process state machine" for a style that doesn't fall into this trap.

Comment: I would advise "two processes state machine", which forces student to decompose correctly comb/seq, without hitting the complex inference mechanisms of the synthesizers.

Comment: In this case, a single-state machine is a more elegant and readable solution of what I am trying to implement. Look below for the motivation of my (just formed) opinion in the discussion that I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is personal preference, but I think most people on here will agree with me on this one... do not use two processes to control your state machine.  The whole previous_state next_state thing is total garbage in my opinion.  It's really confusing and it tends to make latches - SURPRISE - You found that out.  Try rewriting your state machine with a single clocked process and only one state machine signal.

Here's my attempt at rewriting your state machine.  Note that I'm not sure the functionality that I have below will work for you.  Simulate it to make sure it behaves the way you expect.  For example the signal en is always tied to '1', not sure if you want that...

```
process (clk_in)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_in) then
    element_out <= '0';
    en <= '1';                      -- this is set to 1 always?
    we <= '0';

    di <= (others => '0');

    case state is

      when st_startwait =>
        if (element_in = '1') then
          acc_x <= resize(data_in, acc_x'length);
          state <= st_add;
        end if;

      when st_add =>
        if (add = '1') then
          acc_y <= acc_x + do;
        else
          acc_y <= acc_x;
        end if;
        state <= st_write;

      when st_write =>
        if (dump = '1') then
          data_out    <= acc_y;
          element_out <= '1';
        else
          di <= acc_y;
          we <= '1';
        end if;
        state <= st_startwait;
    end case;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: I disagree. www.gaisler.com/doc/vhdl2proc.pdf‎

Comment: Again, that's why I said it was personal preference.  I know plenty of people who prefer the two state approach.  To me the code on that PDF is borderline unreadable.  And he advocates just using two processes per file... which to me sounds like a nightmare.  I like to create processes for things that perform certain tasks, like look for a start bit, or count to 1024 over and over again and provide a pulse when done.  I can't imagine putting that all into one process.

Comment: I read the paper of Gaisler, and while I agree with certain aspects I am not going to follow it all the time. Actually, the only argument of Gaisler is "readability". Now I can clearly see a trade-off between readability (defined as separation of comb/seq. is more readable than not) and the ability to describe more complicated machinery. In this case I want to use registers to repeat part of the output signal. Of course, this is not necessary, but I think that this makes my design more robust (can't continue) here.

Comment: I encourage people to use what comes naturally to them.  Both styles have issues.  For example, had you correctly added reset, then you would also need to reset all of signals that are outputs of the process, otherwise, the ones you leave off will have a hold condition during reset.  With VHDL-2008 and process(all), the sensitivity list issues are gone.  Hence, I can use a process similar to yours, leaving off the clock, use process(all), change all assignments of state to next_state, and add the default assignment (before case statement) of: "next_state <= state ;"

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you need supplemental (clocked) registers (D flip flops).

Your need to ask yourself "what occurs to acc_x if the FSM is in (let say) state st_add ?". Your answer is "I dont want to modify acc_x in this state". So : write it explicitely, using clocked registers (such as the one used for state ; you can augment the clocked process with these supplemental registers). Do that Everywhere. That is  the rule. Otherwise, synthesizers will infer transparent latches to memorize the previous value of acc_x : but these transparent latches violate the synchronous design principles. They structurally imply combinatorial loops in your designs, which are bad.

Put another way : ask yourself what is combinatorial and where are the registers ? If  you have registers in mind, code them explicitly. Do not make combinatorial signals assigned and read in the same process.

Comment: I understand this now and I have tested the single-process solution of Russell and it works---he has done exactly what you suggest. Unfortunately I cannot give more than one credit and he did more answering, so the credit goes to him. Thanks a lot for explaining this!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the inferred latches is that the case in the last process does
not drive all signals in all possible combinations of the sensitive signals.
So the process can finish without altering some of the output data for some of
the signal values to the process.  To hold output in this way is the operation
of a latch, so latches are therefore inferred by the synthesis tool.

The latches applies only to `acc_x`, `acc_y`, and `data_out`, since all other
signals are assigned a default value in the beginning of the process.

You can fix this by either driving a default value for the last 3 signals in
the beginning of the process, for example `'X'` for all bit to allow synthesis
freedom:

```
data_out <= (others => 'X');
acc_x    <= (others => 'X');
acc_y    <= (others => 'X');
```

Alternatively can you can ensure that all outputs are driven in all branches of
the case, and you should then also add a `when others =>` branch to the case.

I suggest that you use the assign of default value to all signals, since this
is easier to write and maintain, instead of having to keep track of assign to
all driven signals in all branches of the case.

Comment: What you say will eliminate the warning but it will also change the output signal which I don't to happen (see discussion below).

Comment: @major**4: The `'X'` is not the final value but an example and should be replaced with a default value that can then be overridden in special cases.  The point is that all signals driven by the process should be generate in every execution of the process, since this is a combinatorial process.